# Cookie not saved in Microsoft Edge

Tags: http, cookies, jwt, microsoft-edge

I am saving a JWT in cookie for authentication by the following code:

```
res.cookie("jwt", my_token, {
  secure: false,
  httpOnly: true,
});
```

This works perfectly in chrome and firefox but not always in edge. The strange think is, that it works when I access the website by the IP address, but not when I use the domain name.

This if how I fetch it:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "post",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
```

I've tried to change the value of credentials but with no avail.

**Edit:**
The cookie is saved using a development server on localhost. The problem exists in deployment using Nginx, in http mode and only accesing the website vie the DNS name, not ip.

The problem can be recreated by hosts remapping using Fiddle.

Comment: Based on the problem you described, I created a simple example and referenced [this article](https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/using-cookies-with-jwt-in-node-js-8fn) to test it in Edge (Version 95.0.1020.38). I found that the code can work normally. I changed localhost to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) and it also worked. So I am afraid I cannot determine the cause of your problem. Could you provide more details, eg the complete code that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: I added some more details

Comment: If this is the case, I think this issue should be related to NginX. It may be incompatible with Edge, and I recommand you could seek more professional advice on the [NginX forum](https://forum.nginx.org/).